# error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException main([Ljava.lang.String;)

Tags: java, exception, javafx

This is my main class for running a simple frame have been created by JavaFX
but I got this error

```
Exception in Application start method Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: controller.TestFrame.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:119)
```

```java
public class TestFrame extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        primaryStage.setTitle("Frame1 Title");
        primaryStage.setScene(
                new Scene(
                        (Parent) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/Frame1.fxml"))
                        , 400
                        , 500));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

}
```

Comment: You didn't declare any static method named `main()`, so why are you confused when it says that no such method exists? Did you *try* the JavaFX [Hello World](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm) program in the documentation? You know, to see how it works.

Comment: this class extended Application class in JavaFX so writing main() method it is not necessary even if I write a main() method that invoke the Application.lunch() method I'll get so many other errors

Comment: Error message says you need a `main()` method. Sample "Hello World" program has a `main()` method. So, perhaps you should have a `main()` method? Or start the program another way? --- If adding a `main()` method gives you other errors, it's probably because those errors are there now, and when it gets past the first error, the others will occur. Don't blame the `main()` method for that.

Comment: Do you have all imports?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html

Comment: yes,I have all imports.and in the  bellow comment i explained which kind of errors I got after adding main() methods

Answer (score 1):

If you want run this class directly, you must add this method to your class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
}
```

Comment: at controller.TestFrame.start(TestFrame.java:20)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)

Comment: at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)

Comment: at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
 ... 1 more

Comment: please post whole stacktrace.

Comment: Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
 at

Comment: com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Controller/Frame1 (wrong name: controller/Frame1)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
 at

Comment: java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)

Comment: at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
 at

Comment: javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
 at controller.TestFrame.start(TestFrame.java:20)
 at

Comment: com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
 at

Comment: com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)

Comment: correct your controller class in your fxml file (this one is wrong [ Controller/Frame1])

Comment: Next time could you edit your answer to include the new information instead of posting it into the chat.